# Why does Zoom H4N insist that the card is full?

Tags: zoom-h4n, sd

I put a freshly formatted (on a PC, FAT32) 16GB SD card into the Zoom H4N, and after recording 3 GB in 5 files, it insists that the card is full.  Simultaneously it shows a large time (hours) remaining on the bottom of the display.

The first thing I did was re-verify the card to make sure it has not gone bad. chkdsk followed by H2test show all is well, and yhe card has nearly 13GB useable space free.

Comment: You will need to format the card in the H4N for it to function correctly ;)

Comment: That would be fine if the H4N *would* format, rather than locking up. If something was bad on the card from a bad flush or something then formatting is supposed to cure that, and not being available in the instance where it's needed is Bad.

Comment: Are you certain the card is really 16GB? Wouldn't be the first time someone had faked the capacity onto a lower spec card. Try [H2testw](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/H2testw.shtml) to check it is what it says it is.

Comment: Yes, I ran h2testw on the card afterwards. My files are fine up to the point it quit (I've not listened through, but spot-check, chkdsk, wav media length are fine). No problems with the card. Oh, I previosly determined that the card was in-spec for size and speed when I got it.